# Div beside the cursor

Tags: jquery

I want to have a div beside my cursor when I mouseenter in an area.

```
jQuery('area').mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('#divToShowBeside').show();
});
```

I want this : #divToShowBeside to be beside my cursor when I mousenter in an area .

Comment: you want tool tip like stuff?

Comment: Use the [Event.pageX](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) property to fetch the current mouse position (either on click or on mousemove), and position the div accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your demo.

```js
var offset = { top: 0, left: 18 };
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    $('#nextToCursor').toggle().offset({ top: (e.pageY + offset.top), left: (e.pageX + offset.left)});
});
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $('#nextToCursor').offset({ top: (e.pageY + offset.top), left: (e.pageX + offset.left)});
});
```

```css
#nextToCursor { display: none; position: fixed; width: 100px; border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nextToCursor">This div is placed next to the cursor after clicking somewhere.</div>
```

Click somewhere in the pane to show/hide your div. Then move the mouse the see the div to go along with your cursor.

Alter the `offset` parameter to position the div relative to the cursor, and remove the `mousemove` event if you don't want the div to move with your mouse (but just pop-up where you clicked the pane).